# Plotly Bars aligned center to the grid

Tags: python, plotly

i wonder if there is way to align the bars in Plotly Bar to the center of the grid cell. I am using plotly express bar and the x axis displays date type values. As shown in the picture below.

[image]

I would like to have my tick label per day, but the bar should be centered in the day and not across the day tick.
it's possible to reproduce the behavior with few lines of code:

```
fig = px.bar(
    x=[datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 1), datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 2), datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 3)],
    y=[2, 4, 5]
)
fig.update_xaxis(dtick=86400000,tickmode='linear',
        ticklabelmode="period")
fig.show()
```

Comment: I don't know if this is an appropriate comment since there is too little information given, but you can determine the spacing, format, and position of the time series data. Please refer to this for [https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#displaying-period-data](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#displaying-period-data).

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It will be easier for us to help if we know how you produced this plot, ideally with a sample dataset and some of your code

Comment: @DerekO you are right, sorry, i edited the question adding a small sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't control the time series data in express well, so I used graph_objects. go allows you to set the x-axis placement and tick units.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import datetime

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=[datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 1), datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 2), datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 3)],
    y=[2, 4, 5],
    xperiod=86400000,
    xperiodalignment="middle"
))
#fig.update_xaxes(dtick=86400000,tickmode='linear', ticklabelmode="period")
fig.update_xaxes(tickmode='linear', ticklabelmode="period")

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: brilliant solution. it's hard to survive in the parameters jungle of plotly functions :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to the `graph_objects` solution, you can keep on using the plotly `express` solution in the following way:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import datetime

fig = px.bar(
    x=[datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 1), datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 2), datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 3)], 
    y=[2, 4, 5], 
)
fig.update_xaxes(
    dtick="D1",
    # tickmode='linear',
    # ticklabelmode="period",
)
```

where you specify `dtick="D1"` (instead of milliseconds) and "linear" is the default value if `tick0` and `dtick` are provided. Also, you don't need `ticklabelmode`. In the case of "D1" `tick0` is ignored but it is a useful parameter when you sample your plot in a monthly series. I found this useful in this combination:

```
dtick="M1",
tick0="2000-01-31",
```

in order to align the bars at the end of the month, or `15` for the middle, or `01` at the beginning.